# Checking internet connection from C++ code

Tags: c++, ping, connectivity, wininet, nic

While working with large codebase for legacy applications, whenever I have seen a piece of code that checks whether an internet connection is active or not, I have mostly seen the uses of functions such as:

```
InternetCheckConnection(L"http://www.google.com",FLAG_ICC_FORCE_CONNECTION,0)
//or
BOOL bConnected = IsNetworkAlive(&dwSens)
//or
InternetGetConnectedState(&dwReturnedFlag, 0)
//or some other functions
```

but there exists a very very simple way to do this where you wouldn't need to include other header files of write code, that is:

```
if (system("ping www.google.com"))
```

My question is that what are the drawbacks, if any, to use `ping` from the code when I need to see if a connection is available or not?

Assuming that `ping` is not going to be disabled on the machines where my software is going to run.

Comment: @Ron: `system` will return the status of the `ping` - it may not be very precise in what it tells you, but it will tell you if you can reach google or not. [Of course, if you can't, it doesn't mean you don't have an internet connection per se, just that google can't be reached by your current internet connection - but since google is quite good at being available just about everywhere, I think it's almost identical]

Comment: Of course - the other question is do you care if you have internet connectivity?  Usually you just care about if you can connect to the server you're about to use; so why not just do it and deal with the failure when it happens  (and what do you do if you lose internet connectivity between your check and your usage of it?)

Comment: @UKMonkey: Yes, it's a bit like the "how do I check if I can write to a file" or many of the other such questions. Of course, if you have a generic application that grabs data from a bunch of servers [or servers that use other servers to collect their data], it may be good to have a simple "You don't seem to be connected to the internet" message, rather than a message like "www.example.com/somewhere/somethng.xml could not be retrieved".

Comment: Including header files is free; creating processes is not. Especially in Linux environments, many applications call external programs to do some work, and it often causes all kinds of troubles (program doesn't exist, wrongly escaped arguments, incompatible versions and so on). Therefore, since you already have a working version, I'd prefer that. You just have more control and avoid messing with potentially unreliable external factors.

Comment: @UKMonkey: In this scenario, I want the user to redirect to the help website for the software; and if there is no internet connectivity then I want to say that refer the local help file because there is no connectivity.
I can do this with `ping` as it returns `0` when there is internet connectivity, otherwise, it returns `1`.

Comment: @LifelongNoob then have it always open the (default) browser to the local help file; which can then run javascript to try redirecting to the online ones.  That way if google is up but your website is down then the user still gets the docs!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The drawback with `system("ping www.google.com")` is twofold:

1. If someone replaced the system `ping` command with their own, it could give you the wrong results [and if the process calling `ping` is running with extra privileges, it could do something "interesting" with that privilege]. This is generic for any `system` operation.
2. You are starting another process, which then has to run and shut down before you get the answer [and of course do more or less the same things that `InternetCheckConnection` does - look up the name, translate it to an IP address, send packet to that address, wait for a response, interpret that response, and so on].

Comment: Thanks, makes sense.
The code has been using `InternetCheckConnection` so far, but the MSDN website says that: `InternetCheckConnection is deprecated. InternetCheckConnection does not work in environments that use a web proxy server to access the Internet. Depending on the environment, use NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile or the NLM Interfaces to check for Internet access instead.`
I was just wondering that why shouldn't I just use `ping`.

Answer (score 1):

According to Microsoft API document **[InternetCheckConnection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wininet/nf-wininet-internetcheckconnectiona)** is deprecated.

> [InternetCheckConnection is available for use in the operating systems specified in the Requirements section. It may be altered or unavailable in subsequent versions. Instead, use NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile or the NLM Interfaces. ]

Instead of this API we can use **[INetworkListManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/netlistmgr/nn-netlistmgr-inetworklistmanager)** interface to check whether Internet is connected or not for windows platform.

Here below is the win32 codebase :

```
        #include <iostream>
        #include <ObjBase.h>      // include the base COM header
        #include <Netlistmgr.h>

        // Instruct linker to link to the required COM libraries
        #pragma comment(lib, "ole32.lib")

        using namespace std;

        enum class INTERNET_STATUS
        {
            CONNECTED,
            DISCONNECTED,
            CONNECTED_TO_LOCAL,
            CONNECTION_ERROR
        };

        INTERNET_STATUS IsConnectedToInternet();

        int main()
        {
            INTERNET_STATUS connectedStatus = INTERNET_STATUS::CONNECTION_ERROR;
            connectedStatus = IsConnectedToInternet();
            switch (connectedStatus)
            {
            case INTERNET_STATUS::CONNECTED:
                cout << "Connected to the internet" << endl;
                break;
            case INTERNET_STATUS::DISCONNECTED:
                cout << "Internet is not available" << endl;
                break;
            case INTERNET_STATUS::CONNECTED_TO_LOCAL:
                cout << "Connected to the local network." << endl;
                break;
            case INTERNET_STATUS::CONNECTION_ERROR:
            default:
                cout << "Unknown error has been occurred." << endl;
                break;
            }
        }

        INTERNET_STATUS IsConnectedToInternet()
        {
            INTERNET_STATUS connectedStatus = INTERNET_STATUS::CONNECTION_ERROR;
            HRESULT hr = S_FALSE;

            try
            {
                hr = CoInitialize(NULL);
                if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                {
                    INetworkListManager* pNetworkListManager;
                    hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_NetworkListManager, NULL, CLSCTX_ALL, __uuidof(INetworkListManager), (LPVOID*)&pNetworkListManager);
                    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                    {
                        NLM_CONNECTIVITY nlmConnectivity = NLM_CONNECTIVITY::NLM_CONNECTIVITY_DISCONNECTED;
                        VARIANT_BOOL isConnected = VARIANT_FALSE;
                        hr = pNetworkListManager->get_IsConnectedToInternet(&isConnected);
                        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                        {
                            if (isConnected == VARIANT_TRUE)
                                connectedStatus = INTERNET_STATUS::CONNECTED;
                            else
                                connectedStatus = INTERNET_STATUS::DISCONNECTED;
                        }

                        if (isConnected == VARIANT_FALSE && SUCCEEDED(pNetworkListManager->GetConnectivity(&nlmConnectivity)))
                        {
                            if (nlmConnectivity & (NLM_CONNECTIVITY_IPV4_LOCALNETWORK | NLM_CONNECTIVITY_IPV4_SUBNET | NLM_CONNECTIVITY_IPV6_LOCALNETWORK | NLM_CONNECTIVITY_IPV6_SUBNET))
                            {
                                connectedStatus = INTERNET_STATUS::CONNECTED_TO_LOCAL;
                            }
                        }

                        pNetworkListManager->Release();
                    }
                }

                CoUninitialize();
            }
            catch (...)
            {
                connectedStatus = INTERNET_STATUS::CONNECTION_ERROR;
            }

            return connectedStatus;
        }
```

Comment: For me this is not working in some cases:
 - If you enable Flight Mode or 
 - If you just lose Internet reach but the network interface is still on or
 - In the case you have several network interfaces such as wired, wifi or mobile/celullar connectivity and as far as you disable used one and other is replacing this one, along this process where SO losses internet connectivity, it is not reported any problem

Comment: This code doesn't help reliably detect an alive connection in a virtualized Windows 7 : when it runs right after Windows start (inside VMware), it reports the connection is established while it is not.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `boost`, you can do the following:

```
static bool has_internet(net::io_context& ioc) {
    tcp::resolver resolver(boost::asio::make_strand(ioc));

    boost::beast::error_code ec;
    auto endpoints = resolver.resolve("google.com", "80", ec);
    if (endpoints.empty() || ec.failed())
        return false;

    return true;
}
```