# Is there an equivalent function in NLM interface for InternetCheckConnection?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, network-programming, msdn

Based on MSDN documentation as follows,

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wininet/nf-wininet-internetcheckconnectiona

> [**InternetCheckConnection** is available for use in the operating systems specified in the Requirements section. It may be altered or unavailable in subsequent versions. Instead, use NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile or the NLM Interfaces. ]

I couldn't find an equivalent version of the [NLM interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/desktop/NLA/nlm-interfaces). If there is one, a small example of snippet would be very helpful.

Comment: Personally, I have no experience with these, but have you seen [`INetwork.IsConnectedToInternet`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/netlistmgr/nf-netlistmgr-inetwork-get_isconnectedtointernet) and possibly [`INetwork.GetConnectivity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/netlistmgr/nf-netlistmgr-inetwork-getconnectivity)?

Comment: @Christian.K I need to verify particular server reachability using the NLM interface. As you can see the 1st param of the method signature 

BOOLAPI InternetCheckConnectionA(
  LPCSTR lpszUrl,
  DWORD  dwFlags,
  DWORD  dwReserved
);

LPCSTR lpszURL - In which we can pass the server URL.

Comment: @ArjunNatarajan "*I need to verify particular server reachability*" - the correct and reliable way to do that is actually *connect to the server*.  NLM (or any other API) won't tell you if a given server can be connected to, you have to actually attempt to connect to it. That is what `InternetCheckConnection()` does internally, which is why it takes a URL as input, so it knows where to connect.

Comment: A workaround is using [`system("ping www.google.com")`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49294741/checking-internet-connection-from-c-code) or run [`Test-Connection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/test-connection?view=powershell-7#outputs) PowerShell command in your app and check the result.